# Permutations of 1 to k among rows and columns of an n-order matrix

Tags: permutations, permutation-matrices

Given a square matrix of order n (no elements are defined yet), some entries are marked, so that every row and column has k `(k<n)` marked entries. Is it possible to define an integer from 1 to k on every marked entry so that any row or column has every number exactly once?

I cannot post images yet (my first post), so here is an written-table example with n=5 and k=3 (marked entries as underlines):

x   _   _   x   _

x   x   _   _   _

_   _   _   x   x

_   x   x   _   _

_   _   x   _   x

The solution exists in this case (there are 36, but existence of one is enough):

x   3   2   x   1

x   x   3   1   2

3   2   1   x   x

1   x   x   2   3

2   1   x   3   x

Or, equivalently: given a table with pre-defined positions in the same quantity for any row or column, can I always find a way to put permutations in the rows and columns at the same time?

Seems to be a classic problem, but I could not find any demonstration.

This problem arises from trying to put teachers in classrooms. Many classrooms have the same teachers, so if I can only look at quantities first, then maybe the distribution becomes easier. It depends on the solution of the above table problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

The marked entries correspond to edges of a bipartite graph with $n$ vertices in each part, all with degree $k$.  You want to colour the edges with $k$ colours, so no edges of the same colour share a vertex.

Using [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem), the graph has a perfect matching.
Colour the corresponding edges with one colour and consider the graph with those edges removed.  This is now a bipartite graph of $n$ vertices, all of degree $k-1$.  Use induction.

Comment: Wow! Never thought it would come from graph theory. Thanks!